# Kotlin flow emits nothing when I call the function second time

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I try to implement deleting user in FirebaseAuth using Kotlin flow (SharedFlow).
In onDeleteAccountClicked() there is delete() method called from FirebaseAuth which may throw AuthReauthenticationRequiredException. When the exception is thrown, app redirects to another fragment to reauthenticate, then call onDeleteAccountClicked() once again, but flow emits nothing.

**ViewModel**

```
    private val _deleteAccount = MutableSharedFlow<() -> Unit>()

    fun onDeleteAccountClicked() {
        logd("outside the viewModelScope")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            logd("inside the viewModelScope")
            _deleteAccount.emit {
                logd("emitting log")
                firebaseAuth.deleteUser()
                //throw AuthReauthenticationRequiredException()
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _deleteAccount
                .onEach {
                    it()
                }
                .catch {
                    if (it is AuthReauthenticationRequiredException) {
                        _redirectToSignInMethodsScreen.emit(Unit)
                    }
                }
                .collect()
        }
    }
```

Logs "outside the viewModelScope" and "inside the viewModelScope" shows every time when the method is called, but "emitting log" only for the first time.

Am I even trying to do it the right way?

Comment: What type does `_deleteAccount` variable have?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this line of code. I edited the post (first line of code).

Comment: `firebaseAuth.deleteUser()` is it function from library? If not can you show an implementation?

Comment: It's not important I think... For tests I commented this line and uncommented next which throws exception

Comment: It is important. With it I can suggest a simpler solution. Why you use such a complex structure to call one function? I think using a `Flow` here just make things more complex.

Comment: So inside .deleteUser() function I call this function https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#delete()

Comment: Do you wait somehow for its result? Result of calling `FirebaseUser.delete`

Comment: @Sergey No, I don't wait

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the code, and it works for me. I called `onDeleteAccountClicked()` three times with delay between calling, and all three logs "emitting log" inside `emit` lambda were printed. Try to remove calling `firebaseAuth.deleteUser()` inside `emit` lambda and test. Calling `FirebaseUser.delete` function when user is already deleted throws `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` exception. Maybe that's why you didn't see logs - because `FirebaseUser.delete` function throws an exception.

I think the structure you use for calling just one function is a bit complicated, I can suggest to get rid of `_deleteAccount` flow and just wrap `firebaseAuth.deleteUser()` inside `try-catch` (you even don't need to launch a coroutine for that):

```
fun onDeleteAccountClicked() {
    try {
        firebaseAuth.deleteUser()
    } catch(e: AuthReauthenticationRequiredException) {
        _redirectToSignInMethodsScreen.emit(Unit)
    }
}
```